Apache to Nginx - query strings
I currently have a legacy application running on Apache that I'm looking to move to nginx.
It has some rewrite rules in .htaccess that I'm looking to replicate in my nginx config, but a bit unsure how to convert them.
htaccess
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2&id2=$3

In the nginx conf, I have:
location / {
   # Serve requests through index.php
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
location ~ \.php$ {
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
   include fastcgi_params;
}

Do I need to add any more custom rewrites to match the .htacess?
Thanks
